# Swift: enum type as a property

Tags: xcode, enums, swift, protocols

Can I store enum type (or class) conforms to protocol to var inside my class?

```
class MyClass : UIViewController {
    var sourceType : InformationServiceItemProtocol = InformationServiceMenuItem.self
}
```

Getting compile error:

```
Type 'InformationServiceMenuItem.Type' Does not conform to protocol 'InformationServiceItemProtocol'
```

cause I getting no compile error here, but here is no single word about protocol:

```
class MyClass : UIViewController {
    var sourceType = InformationServiceMenuItem.self
}
```

achieved it by putting

```
var sourceType : InformationServiceItemProtocol.Type = InformationServiceMenuItem.self
```

no compile errors here, but I can't use it, anywhere I'm trying to access sourceType I'm getting compilation failed with

```
1.  While emitting IR SIL function @_TFC12AeroflotIPad28InformationServiceSideMenuVC9tableViewfS0_FTGSQCSo11UITableView_21cellForRowAtIndexPathGSQCSo11NSIndexPath__GSQCSo15UITableViewCell_ for 'tableView' at /Users/PathToProject/InformationServiceSideMenuVC.swift:25:11
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Volumes/Macintosh_Aditional_SSD/AlsoApplications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

for example:

```
protocol InformationServiceItemProtocol {
    var title: String { get }
    var subitems: InformationServiceItemProtocol[]? { get }
    class func count () -> Int
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sourceType.count() // if I'll replace it with 'return 0' no compilation failed message
}
```

Comment: what type do you hope to get from this `InformationServiceMenuItem.self` in `sourceType`? if you answer this question, you will answer to your original question as well.

Comment: I want to get type that conforms to protocol

Comment: sooo... then, why do you expect an `InformationServiceItemProtocol` if you know you want to get a `Type`? set the type of the `var` precisely you'd like to get, that is what the quoted error message liked to tell you.

Comment: I have a couple of class func in protocol and I actually need a type, not instance of it's class. I need to be able to create instances of that type and access class functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between types and metatypes:

```
var sourceType: InformationServiceItemProtocol.Protocol = InformationServiceMenuItem.self
```

EDIT to answer edits:

That's a compiler bug. Report it to Apple.

Comment: thank you, I solved problem, you gave me a good tip! But have a look please, I updated my question